# Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with degree function $\varphi$ and $R$ not a field. If $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$ be two elements in $R$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with degree function $\varphi$ and $R$ is not a field. Prove the following:

(1) Let $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$ be two elements in $R$. Suppose that $a\mid b$ and $b \nmid a$. Prove that  $\varphi (a) < \varphi(b)$

(2) Suppose that $\varphi(ab)= \varphi(a) \varphi(b)$ for all $a,b \in R\setminus\{0\}$. Prove that an element $u \in R$ is a unit if and only  if $\varphi (u)=1$

By my book's definition, a Euclidean domain is a Euclidean ring which is an integral domain, which satisfies the following:

a) If a,b∈R and ab≠0, then $\varphi$(a)≤$\varphi$(ab)

b) If a,b∈R and b≠0, then there exists q,r∈R such that a=qb+r with r=0, or r≠0 and φ(r)<φ(b)

By my book as wel, if R is an Euclidean domain, then R is also an integral domain and a principal ideal domain.

Comment: You don't have to prove (a) and (b): they're given.

Comment: @egreg, ha ha, yes forgive me. That is stated there, isnt it.

Comment: For part (2): suppose $u$ is a unit; then $1=uv$ for some $v$ and so $\varphi(1)=\varphi(u)\varphi(v)$. But $1=1^2$, so $\varphi(1)=\varphi(1)^2$, Hence $\varphi(1)=1$ (it can't be $0$, why?).

Comment: @egreg, well, R is assumed to be a nonzero ring and the multiplicative and additive identity elements of R will then be unequal?

Comment: If $\varphi(1)=0$, then $\varphi(a)=0$ for all $a\ne0$. But this clearly implies $R$ is a field. By the way, you should have kept the definition of Euclidean domain you're using (there are different sorts of it).

Comment: What is your definition of a Euclidean domain? (there are a few variations)

Comment: @BillDubuque, I have added the definition

Answer (score 3):

It seems the following.

(1) Since $a,b\in R$ and $b\ne 0$, then there exist $q,r\in R$ such that $a=qb+r$ with $r=0$, or $r\ne 0$ and $\varphi(r)<\varphi(b)$. Since $b \nmid a$, $r\ne 0$. Hence $\varphi(r)<\varphi(b)$. Since $a\mid b$ and $a\mid qb$, $a\mid r$ too. Therefore there exists an element $c\in R$ such that $r=ac$. Since $ac=r\ne 0$, we have $\varphi(a)\le \varphi(r)<\varphi(b)$.

(2) The necessity is already proven by egreg, so we prove the sufficiency. Let $\varphi(u)=1$. There exist $q,r\in R$ such that $1=qu+r$ with $r=0$, or $r\ne 0$ and $\varphi(r)<\varphi(u)$. Assume that $r\ne 0$. Then $\varphi(r)=0$. Since $r=1r\ne 0$, $\varphi(1)\le \varphi(r)=0$, so $\varphi(1)=0$. As showed egreg, in this case $R$ is a field, a contradiction.  So $r=0$. Then $u$ is a unit.

Comment: can you explain this line to me 'Since b∤a, r≠0. Hence φ(r)<φ(b)'??

Comment: @cele If $r=0$, then $a=qb$, but $b \nmid a$. So $r\ne 0$. Then, by (b), $\varphi(r)<\varphi(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to assume $R$ is Euclidean domain. Euclidean ring suffices. In this answer, I will show slightly generalize version of problem (2). Following is definition of Euclidean ring: Let $N$ be the set of non negative integers and $R$ a commutative ring. $R$ is a Euclidean ring if there is a function $\varphi : R\setminus \{0\}\to N$ such that:

$(1)$ if $a,b\in R$ and $ab\neq 0$, then $\varphi (a)\leq \varphi (ab)$;

$(2)$ if $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0$, then there exists $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ with $r=0$ or $r\ne 0$ and $\varphi (r)\lt \varphi (b)$.

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean ring and $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$. Then $a$ is a unit in $R$ if and only if $\varphi (a) =\varphi (1_R)$.

Note: Since we are talking about unit in the exercise, it is implicitly assume $R$ has a multiplicative identity.

**Proof:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $a$ is a unit in $R$. Then $\exists a^{-1}\in R$ such that $aa^{-1}=1_R$ and $a1_R=a$. By $(1)$ axiom of Euclidean ring, we have $\varphi (a)\leq \varphi (aa^{-1})=\varphi (1_R)$ and $\varphi (1_R)\leq \varphi (a1_R)=\varphi (a)$. Thus $\varphi (a)=\varphi (1_R)$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely, suppose $\varphi (a)=\varphi (1_R)$. By $(2)$ axiom of Euclidean ring, $\exists q,r\in R$ such that $1_R=qa+r$ with $r=0$ or $r\neq 0$ and $\varphi (r)\lt \varphi (a)$. If $r\neq 0$, then $\varphi (r)\lt \varphi (a)=\varphi (1_R)$. But by $(1)$ axiom, $\varphi (1_R)\leq \varphi (r1_R)=\varphi (r)$. So $r=0$ and $1_R=qa=aq$. Thus $q$ is multiplicative inverse of $a$. Hence $a$ is unit.

If you assume $\varphi$ preserve multiplication, i.e. $\varphi (ab)=\varphi (a) \varphi (b)$, and $R$ is not field (commutative division ring), then $\varphi (1_R)=1$.